A 111 years old mosaic
What letter is missing in this mosaic?


The missing letter is:

 E

What does the image represent?

 It's the Olympic rings logo - five interlocking rings of blue, yellow, black, green and red - which was first introduced in 1913, 111 years ago (hence the title).

What should we do with it?

 Take the eight letters that make up each coloured ring (beware the overlaps). We get (reading clockwise from top-left):

 Blue = UEARCNEL
 Black = AHCLAOCR
 Red = CIDANRAL
 Yellow = AROOCAMN
 Green = OLCRIDCO

Now note that four of these...

 ...are anagrams of words which are hues of that colour:

 Blue = CERULEAN
 Black = CHARCOAL
 Red = CARDINAL
 Yellow = MACAROON

 We cannot do this for Green, however. There is no common anagram of OLCRIDCO. However, if we add a letter 'E' we can make CROCODILE! And the puzzle is solved :)


That was insanely quick! Perfect solve ;)

@Jujustum Thanks, I really liked the puzzle. The necessary link immediately sprang to mind thanks to current events and the solution path unfolded when I started to apply 'puzzle hunt brain' :)
